# Is it valid to const_cast the key value of a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, constants

Long story short is it valid to:

```
    map<int,int>m;
    m.insert( make_pair( 1, 40 ) );
    for( map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
    {
        const_cast<int&>( it->first ) = 2;
    }
```

it works, I have encountered myself in this problem, which in the real case the map was a map of two classes, `map<classA,classB>` and to access the non-const members of the class I had to`const_cast<classA&>(it->first).NonConstFunction()`, this was the first idea that came up on my mind, is it just okay to do this or is there something *better*?

Comment: I don't know where specifically it's said, but I'm fairly sure it's `const` for a good reason.

Comment: main first one should be that its the key of the map, the problem is that the classes has datatype members which should be changed in some times, and a map with these classes is possibly the best way for my solution

Comment: If you want similar keys then use `std::multimap`. What you are doing is dangerous as the whole map has the same key without its knowledge!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not allowed. When you modify the key in-place like this, the map will not "realize" that the value has changed, so it might need to move that node to a new position in the tree it maintains internally to store the data. If the tree is no longer sorted, almost any other operation on the tree may well crash and burn.

To do it correctly, you need to get a copy of the key/value pair, remove the old node from the map, modify your copy outside the map, then insert the modified copy back into the map.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the first part, could you explain it in a more non-technical way?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: The map maintains the items it contains in order. When you modify a key, they may not be in order any more. It depends on their being in order, so when/if they're not, it won't work correctly any more. An unordered_map won't be any better -- it stores a value based on a hash of the key, so when you update a key, it needs to re-compute the hash and insert at the correct spot in the table for that hash.

Comment: Oh i got it now, but see, in the main problem, its storing a class at the key value with an overloaded operator == which the member that it compares between the classes remain unchanged, even in this occasion would that happen?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: `map` uses `operator<`, not `operator==`. If you have objects with equal keys comparing as not-equal (or vice versa) the whole thing sounds...somewhat suspect at best.

Comment: @ViniyoShouta: If you have elements in ClassA which do not participate in the comparison operation at all, then it is safe to modify them. Declare them as `mutable` (which means "even though this object is const, these members might change). Many people run in fear from this construct.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, thanks for the answer Jerry, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428205/overloaded-operator-generates-errors-when-using-stdmap